# Use AucTeX with "latexmk -pvc": jump to errors

Tags: auctex

Currently, I edit LaTeX files by running `latexmk -pvc` in the background to generate PDF automatically upon change to be previewed in Evince. However, when there is a syntax error, AucTeX is not able to show it. How can I complete this integration by jumping to errors given by the `latexmk` process?

Comment: So `TeX-next-error` and `Tex-previous-error`do not work? Are you using `auctex-latexmk`?

Comment: @Timm No I'm not using it -- I'm running `latexmk -pvc` in the background so PDF gets rebuilt automatically upon saving. `TeX-next-error` won't work.

Comment: Do you know that AUCTeX can automatically compile the document in a way similar to latexmk and open the viewer at the end of a successful compilation just with C-c C-a? In this way you can use error reporting tools shipped with AUCTeX, including TeX-error-overview. Parsing the output of latexmk in AUCTeX is a bit tricky

Comment: I suggest to mention -pvc the question title. I'm using `auctex-latexmk` with `(setq TeX-save-query nil)` and the files are automatically saved when compiling with `C-c C-c`. I don't see much of an advantage of using `latexmk -pvc` instead.

Comment: @giordano Thank you for pointing it out, I didn't use it before. There is a drawback however: every time I run it, the focus switches to Evince. I have to manually switch back to Emacs.

Comment: Maybe your workflow is different from mine, but usually I compile a document when I want to look to the output ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I have dealing with the same issue. That is my solution, it is a bit late but it could be useful.

```
(defun brust-LaTeX-next-error (args)
  (interactive "p")
  (if-let ((active-buffer (TeX-active-buffer)))
      (if (< 15 args)
          (TeX-error-overview)
        (when (< 3 args)
          (save-excursion
            (set-buffer active-buffer)
            (TeX-parse-all-errors)
            (if TeX-error-list
                (message ":::: WARNING :::: There are errors ::::")
              (message ":::: Be happy, your LaTeX code has no errors ::::"))))
        (call-interactively 'TeX-next-error))
    (message "There is no active buffer")))
```

I guess that AUCTeX creates the list of errors once the compiling precess finishes.
So, the problem with `latexmk -pvc` is that the process never ends and the list is never created.

The idea is to replace `TeX-next-error` with previous function.
First, it checks whether there is an active process or not.
When you call `brust-LaTeX-next-error` with prefix argument `C-u` it creates the list from the active buffer with the same functions that AUCTeX does when the process ends (again I guess).
So, they should interact nicely.
When you call it with no prefix argument it just calls `TeX-next-error`.

As an extra functionality when you call it with double prefix argument `C-u C-u` a buffer with all errors listed is created.